# google Cloud Vision API: node.js and an image URI, how to invoke vision.detectText()?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to detect text in a remote image with the google Cloud Vision API, but can't seem to get the vision.detectText() syntax right.

How do I use vision.detectText() when there is no cloud storage bucket?

I'm thinking I can/should ignore the reference to storage.bucket() indicated on https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text

I have:

```
 vision.detectText('https://drive.google.com/file
   /d/0Bw4DMtLCtPMkWVlIVXE5a2ZpQlU/view?usp=drivesdk')
          .then((results) => {
            const detections = results[0];
            console.log('Text:');
            detections.forEach((text) => console.log(text));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
          });
```

the console reports:

```
ERROR: { PartialFailureError: A failure occurred during this request.
at /Users/node_modules/@google-cloud/vision/src/index.js:434:15
at /Users/node_modules/@google-cloud/vision/src/index.js:126:5
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
errors: 
[ { image:  'https://drive.google.com/file/d
 /0Bw4DMtLCtPMkNFFselFhU0RMV2c/view?usp=drivesdk',
   errors: [Object] } ],
 response: { responses: [ [Object] ] },
 message: 'A failure occurred during this request.' }
```

I have tried using:

```
vision.detectText(storage.bucket().file('https://......
```

but the error is:

```
Error: A bucket name is needed to use Cloud Storage.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not setting your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. The following code works as tested:

```
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const vision = Vision();
const fileName = 'http://example.com/eg.jpg';

vision.detectText(fileName)
  .then((results) => {
    const detections = results[0];

    console.log('Text:');
    detections.forEach((text) => console.log(text));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
```

To try it out with our sample, pass a URI (e.g. http URI) to the [detect.js](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/detect.js) sample as:

```
node detect.js fulltext http://www.identifont.com/samples/houseindustries/NeutraText.gif
```

Comment: vision.detectFaces() does not indicate a bucket param like vision.detectText()

Comment: Updated to demonstrate text detection

Comment: well, I have no GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable; I'm not sure how that would have been set. I re-built my client_secret.json auth file and confirm that my upload-to-Drive works as it did before. My vision.js has a drive.files.get() that is also happy with auth as I do get the webviewLink parameter back. However, my vision.detectText() still fails as above. As you suggested, I tried $ node detect.js fulltext http://www.identifont.com/samples/houseindustries/NeutraText.gif  and it chokes  detect.js:779
  .recommendCommands()
   ^
TypeError: require(...).demand(...).comman

Comment: boom! new information. I swapped out my google-drive URI for yours and the darn thing works. So, is that a bug?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it obliquely responds properly to the original question. SO police: I'm going to open, answer, and accept a new question relating to the buggish effect of using the google drive v3 parameter webviewLink as an input to vision.detectText(). I hope this is the approved process. If not, please let me off with a warning.

Comment: @user1405141 You're hitting the "grace" quota, if you try to process a large number of images without credentials, you will begin seeing 401 responses.